# Finding percentage increase

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers, percentages

white bread: serving size 63 g 
Protein - 5.2 g

Wholemeal bread : serving size 53g 
Protein- 6.5 g

Which bread contains more protein and by what percentage ?

The answer is whole meal bread , 4.01%  but I don't know how to get it . Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percentage of proteins in the white bread is $\dfrac{5.2}{63}\cdot 100=8.25 \%$

The percentage of proteins in the wholemeal bread is $\dfrac{6.5}{53}\cdot 100=12.26 \%$

and the difference is $ 4.01 \%$